# How to check and remove the additional back slash coming in account for for apostrophe in PHP?

Tags: php, json, str-replace, backslash, stripslashes

I've a string in a variable titled `$str` as follows.  This I got after converting it into JSON format. So the one more additional slash is added by JSON so please ignore it as it would not display while showing the string.

```
$str ="Let\\'s\nIt\\'s\nHe\\'s\nShe\\'s"; # \n is used for new line character, please ignore it
```

Now I want to check the presence of such backslash/es in a string and if they are present remove them and get the desired cleaned up string. In above case the output string should be(after converting it into JSON format) : **"Let\'s\nIt\'s\nHe\'s\nShe\'s"**

I tried below code but it didn't work out for me:

```
$str         = br2nl(str_replace('\\','',$str));
function br2nl($buff = '') {
    $buff = mb_convert_encoding($buff, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    $buff = preg_replace('#<br[/\s]*>#si', "\n", $buff);
    $buff = trim($buff);

    return $buff;
  }
```

Can some one please help me in this regard please?

Comment: replace one \ str_replace('\','',$str)

Comment: @AmanRawat:It can't be done. It gives syntax error. As we have to use extra slash for each slash in PHP.

Comment: How about `strip_slashes` or even `json_decode` on the string?

Comment: @vakata: I tried stripslashes, convert it into JSON and got following result : Let\\'s\nIt\\'s\nHe\\'s\nShe\\'s. Still the desired result is missing.

Comment: I meant a simple `echo stripslashes("Let\\'s\nIt\\'s\nHe\\'s\nShe\\'s");` - it will get you the exact result you described. Just keep in mind it is probably best to decode the same way you encoded the string.

Comment: @vakata:I tried the same thing but I didn't get the desired output string.

Comment: @PHPNut you need `$str = str_replace('\\','\',$str);` cuz you are currently double escaping

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you're asking. Why do you have those slashes in there in the first place? I doubt they're there on purpose, your "actual" text is probably not supposed to contain those, right? JSON will add one more slash to escape backslashes, yes. Why is this undesirable? If you do not want the backslashes in your data then you shouldn't have backslashes in your data to begin with, not manually fiddle with text format escapes.

Comment: Read: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Still I didn't get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

As previously suggested, `stripslashes()` is the best way to do this:

```
<?php
  $dirty ="Let\\'s\nIt\\'s\nHe\\'s\nShe\\'s";
  $clean = stripslashes($dirty);
  echo $clean."\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
Let's
It's
He's
She's
```